# C Sharp DateTime Format

Tags: c#, date, datetime, string-formatting

**UPDATE** This looks to be a bug in Windows 7.  I tested the same scenario with Windows 8 and I cannot replicate this there.  Please see the [MS Bug Report](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/83a04368-6fcc-4c9a-8846-95038e5944b0) that I posted on this issue if you want more information.  Thank you again to all that helped.

**UPDATE 2** The error happens on Server 2008 R2 as well (Kind of expected that)

**Original Submission**

Using the examples on the following page [Date Formats](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) I am able to control the format of my date.  However, one of my clients, using Windows 7, modified their calendar to display their short date like this 'ddd MM/dd/yy', see the image for the settings. [image: Short Date Format].

This displays the clock like this [image].

This works fine except when I use a date on their machine. When I format the date like the following...

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt); //the result is 06 04 13, notice the spaces
```

If I take off the ddd to display the day of week in the calendar settings and use the same format option I see the following...

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt); //the result is 06/04/13, this time it has forward slashes
```

The .ToShortDateString() option on the date gives me "Tue 06/04/13" and crashes when going into a database.  This is how the issue was found.

Outside of hard coding the format, i.e. joining the month to the forward slash to the day etc, does anyone know of what else I can try to get this to work?

Comment: It sounds like you are formatting the date as a string in order to send it in via some SQL. Have you considered using command parameters for this instead of string formatting?

Comment: +1 to Michael's comment. Unless a textual representation is your end goal, you should avoid string conversions.

Comment: Yes, this is a pretty old app.  It does have a sql string that is just passed in.  I was hoping to avoid converting to command parameters and wait till I could convert this to EF.  That does sound like a very good idea.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Michael Gunter - Your suggestion worked.  If you post that as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are formatting the date as a string in order to send it in via some SQL. Have you considered using command parameters for this instead of string formatting?

Answer (score 2):

**Edited To Note:** This looks to be a bug with Windows 7. When changing the short date pattern via the control panel, using the "additional settings" tab as in the OP's post, both the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture's date separator gets changed as well.

When you modify the short date format, it looks like the first non-format character is picked up as the date separator for the current culture. Both CurrentCulture and CUrrentUiCulture are modified to reflect that [unintended] customization. Looks like some [bright] developer made the [unwarranted] assumption that nobody would ever have a short date format that included something like day of the week.

Nice catch! Are you going to report the bug to Microsoft?

If you use the invariant culture to format dates, etc., user settings won't affect you. Try something like

```
String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , "{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);
```

or use an instance of the culture you want:

```
CultureInfo usa = CultureInfo.GetCultureINfo("en-US") ;
string.Format( usa , "{0:MM/dd/yy}" , dt ) ;
```

However, if the culture you specified matches the current culture set for the Windows OS, user customizations are applied: meaning, you'll have the same problem unless you use a culture that isn't the current windows culture.

More details at MDSN:

- [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx54z3k7.aspx)
- [Standard DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Without specifying a specific culture, you'll get the current user's `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` with any user-specified mods applied to it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunately culture format did not resolve the issue either.  I expected that would be the solution too, but I think that the space in the settings after the ddd was kicking the separator into a space (kind of like in Europe they use . for a separator).  It did format correctly, but the spaces still appeared.

Comment: @Gouber80. Interesting. I'd have to call this a Windows 7 bug. See my amended answer. The problem does not manifest itself if you use the InvariantCulture (just checked).

Comment: I would agree it should have been fixed with the CurrentCulture - if you see the answer from crash he also noticed that it does not show up with the InvariantCulture.  I think that I will put this on the Win 7 forums.  It has been a while since I have found something might be a potential windows issue ;).

Answer (score 2):

Using the InvariantCulture should work.  I created a test console app to check it.  The code changes the thread's current culture to be the Invariant one:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            /// Displays '06 04 13'

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", System.DateTime.Now));

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            /// Displays '06/04/13'

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", System.DateTime.Now));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a test of this and it works.  I upvoted it because you answered what I was asking for, since Michael's comment ended up being a more appropriate solution I am waiting to see if he posts it as an answer.  I will give him till tomorrow.  Then I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: BTW, this looks completely like a Microsoft bug.  The date should be displayed with slashes even if the short date format in Windows is set to 'ddd MM/dd/yy'.  I left the WIndows setting to 'ddd MM/dd/yyyyy' since it looks good in the Windows task bar.  But I noticed that Outlook was showing the dates w/o the slashes (same problem as yours.)  Maybe you should report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, others have mentioned that too.  Please see the link in my answer, I posted this to the MS forums if you are interested in following.

Comment: This is a .Net bug, you can report it here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in more information on this please go to the MS Forums post that I put [HERE](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/83a04368-6fcc-4c9a-8846-95038e5944b0).